# How search results like Myntra and Jabong are developed?

Tags: java, web-applications, e-commerce, angular-ui-bootstrap, vs-web-application-project

though my question is very theroitical, want to know using what tech, search results like myntra.com and jabong.com are developed? I want to develop the same for my web app and looking for best possible ways, lookwise, performance wise nd user friendliness!!!

Comment: `my question is very theroitical` and you know that this site is for specific programming problems?

Comment: Yes I know, but since this question was important for me to ask and know about it, that's why asked, assuming this is the best place where people can answer based on their knwoledge and experiences and its harmless!

Answer (score 4):

It is depending on which database you use in your web application.
There is full text search facility in MongoDB.
You can use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) for text search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use open source searching and sorting techniques like Apache Solr

visit http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Solr Uses the Lucene Search Library and Extends it, that makes is fast and efficient.